# How to set OpenvSwitch to evict newest flows when memory is full instead of the oldest ones?

Tags: openflow, sdn, openvswitch

I am currently trying to overflow the OvS controller with the flow tables and make it reject new rules and subsequently, new packets.
I found this in documentation:

> Flow Table Configuration
>          Limit flow table 0 on bridge br0 to a maximum of 100 flows:
>
> ```
>           ovs-vsctl -- --id=@ft  create  Flow_Table  flow_limit=100  over‐
>           flow_policy=refuse -- set Bridge br0 flow_tables=0=@ft
> ```

So, I guess I need to implement firstly flow_policy = refuse, and do it for all 255 tables. Nevertheless, whenever I try to run this command, it returns me:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo ovs-vsctl -- --id=@ft  create  Flow_Table  flow_limit=100  over‐flow_policy=refuse -- set Bridge br0 flow_tables=0=@ft 
ovs-vsctl: **Flow_Table does not contain a column whose name matches "over‐flow_policy"**
```

Is there any way to set the policy to refuse for all the tables, and why do I get this mistake?

Comment: I am very sorry, I found that the dash in documentation: http://openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-vsctl.8.txt was not supposed to be in over‐flow_policy; so that it is actually overflow_policy. Still, it would be great to know how to set the policy for 255 tables at once.

Answer (score 1):

you should try using overflow_policy instead of over-flow_policy..it'll works!!